# Check the elements in two columns of different dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes.

Df1

```
Id | Name | Remarks
---------------------
1  | A    | Not bad
1  | B    | Good
2  | C    | Very bad
```

Df2

```
Id | Name | Place |Job
-----------------------
1  | A    | Can   | IT
2  |C     | Cbe   | CS
4  |L     | anc   | ME
5  | A    | cne   | IE
```

Output

```
Id | Name | Remarks  |Results
------------------------------
1  | A    | Not bad  |True
1  | B    | Good     |False
2  | C    | VeryGood |True
```

That is the result should be true if same id and name are present in both dataframes. I tried

```
df1['Results']=np.where(Df1['id','Name'].isin(Df2['Id','Name']),'true','false')
```

But it was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator parameter and compare `both` values:

```
df = Df1[['id','Name']].merge(Df2[['Id','Name']], indicator='Results', how='left')
df['Results'] = df['Results'].eq('both')
```

Your solution is possible by compare index values by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df1['Results']= Df1.set_index(['id','Name']).index.isin(Df2.set_index(['id','Name']).index)
```

Or compare tuples from both columns:

```
df1['Results']= Df1[['id','Name']].agg(tuple, 1).isin(Df2[['id','Name']].agg(tuple, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve by `merge` like @jezrael 's answer.

You can also achieve it with `np.where`,`list comprehension` and `zip` like below:

```
df1['Results']=np.where([str(i)+'_'+str(j)==str(k)+'_'+str(l) for i,j,k,l in zip(Df1['ID'],Df1['Name'],Df2['ID'],Df2['Name'])],True,False)
```